# writing a map function in couchdb db that inserts another doc into a doc

Tags: couchdb

I have two types of docs in my CouchDB database (doc.doc_type == doc1 and doc.doc_type == doc2)

the structure of doc1 is something like this:

```
{
    _id: 123123,
    _rev:1251231,
    doc_type: doc1,
    uid: 1
}
```

The structure of doc 2 is like this:

```
 {
     _id: 123123,
     _rev:1251231,
     doc_type: doc2,
     uid: 1
     docid: 1
 }
```

I want to write a view where I collate all the docs where the doc_type is doc1, but insert the doc2 as an array in doc1 through a map func.

I had written a map function like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
function(doc) {
    var d = []
    if (doc.doc_type == "doc2") {
        d.push(doc)
    }
    if (doc.doc_type == "doc1") {
        var d1 = d.filter(d => {d.uid == doc.uid})
        doc['doc2'] = d1
    }
    emit(doc._id, doc)
}
```

But this is throwing an error. Does CouchDB recognize filter and map?  What is my alternative here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is too modern (no `=>`). But I think you misunderstand how the map works -- it will only ever be passed a single document, so there is nothing for you to filter. If you have a `doc1` the `d` array will *always* be empty.

Comment: CouchDB 3.1 should support modern JS.